# How do I structure a list horizontally in python?

Tags: python

My code looks like this

```py
Teachers_field = [Teachers[0] +" "+ Spirituality, Teachers[1] +" "+ Spirituality_Science +" "+ [Teachers[2] + Science +" "+ Teachers[3] + science +" "+ Teachers[4] + science +" "+ Teachers[5] + Spirituality_Science
```

In the editor they are all lined vertically and they are outputted like that

But I want my code to look like this

```
Teachers_field = 
 Teachers[0] + Spirituality +" "+   
 Teachers[1] + Spirituality_Science +" "+ 
 Teachers[2] + Science +" "+ 
 Teachers[3] + science +" "+ 
 Teachers[4] + science +" "+ 
 Teachers[5] + Spirituality_Science]
```

How do I write the code horizontally and also make the code horizontally. And I can't use `\n`. Is there even a way? Or am I stuck on a dead end.

Comment: What does `make the code horizontally` mean? Isn't it `write the code horizontally`?

Comment: At the eand of each line, put \, so you can type code in newlines. Remember to not add spaces after the \.

Comment: Which list? I see no list!

Comment: I guess what I forgot to write was "and make the output of the code horizontal".

Comment: And appearantly I dont know the difference between vertical and horizontal. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can add a backward slash. Like this:

```
Teachers_field = \
 Teachers[0] + Spirituality +" "+   \
 Teachers[1] + Spirituality_Science +" "+ \
 Teachers[2] + Science +" "+ \
 Teachers[3] + science +" "+ \
 Teachers[4] + science +" "+ \
 Teachers[5] + Spirituality_Science]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like those additional backward slashes for line continuation. They look ugly and the code will break if you have an invisible whitespace character following the backslash.

You can do it like this.

```
Teachers_field = (
 Teachers[0] + Spirituality + " " +   
 Teachers[1] + Spirituality_Science + " " + 
 Teachers[2] + Science + " " +
 Teachers[3] + science + " " +
 Teachers[4] + science + " " +
 Teachers[5] + Spirituality_Science]
)
```

Comment: It would be really nice (and fair) if the downvoter could explain what's the problem with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `\n`?

```
Science = " Indeed!"
Spirituality = " Not really."
Spirituality_Science = " Yes please."
Teachers = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four",
  "Five",
  "Six"
]
Teachers_field = (
 Teachers[0] + Spirituality + "\n" +
 Teachers[1] + Spirituality_Science + "\n" +
 Teachers[2] + Science + "\n" +
 Teachers[3] + Science + "\n" +
 Teachers[4] + Science + "\n" +
 Teachers[5] + Spirituality_Science
)

print(Teachers_field)
```

https://repl.it/repls/DaringEnragedLogins